# iOS App Groups - Can I use more than one app group in the same app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, ios-app-group

I have an app which is using shared NSUserDefaults saved in an app group called e.g  com.myappgroup.one. The use of this app group was a mistake.

I now want to update the app with a new version. In this version I have a new app group called e.g com.myappgroup.two which is what the app group was previous to the app release with the error (i.e com.myappgroup.one)

I want to still be able to access the NSUserDefaults previously saved under com.myappgroup.one. Is it possible to use two app groups in the same app, and if so can I specifiy which group to check in for my NSUserDefaults ?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple app groups. To access user defaults from an app group you need to specifically name the app group you want to access.  `UserDefaults.standard` just access the normal, non-app group defaults.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Do you know how I specify the app group in code ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init

Comment: That’s the suite name - problem is I have two app groups under the same suite name and need to specify which app group. Guessing it can’t be done.

Comment: The suite name is the app group name.  ie you would use `defaults(suiteName:"com.myappgroup.one")` and `defaults(suiteName:"com.myappgroup.two")`

Comment: Thanks - in the end the issue was my suitename was different from the actual app group name ticked in the config - therefore it was bombing out and saving in the standard user defaults. In the end I wrote a script in the new version to grab the missaved version and save to the correct place.